# Как проверить заполненность двух полей? (и деактивировать кнопку, если ни одно поле не заполнено)

Tags: jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы если ни одно из двух полей не заполнено, то кнопка отправки была бы не активна, а активна когда хотя бы одно поле заполнено?

```
<form id="f">
<input type="email" id="mail" onkeyup='checkParams()' class="form-control control" placeholder="Введите Вашу почту" /> 
<input type="text" id="phone" onkeyup='checkParams()' class="form-control control" placeholder="Введите номер телефона" />
    <input type="text" id="policynum" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите номер счета..." /> 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button style="margin-top:-17px" type="submit" id="btnCheckPolicy" class="btn btn-default" disabled> Оплатить</button>
    </span>
    </form>
    </div>
    <span id="valid"></span>
    <div id="policycheckresult">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var pattern = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,6})$/;
            var mail = $('#mail');
            var phone = $('#phone');
                if(mail.length >= 1 || phone.length >=1 ) {
            $('#btnCheckPolicy').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnCheckPolicy').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: `Кнопка активна = поле 1 заполнено И поле 2 заполнено;` - что вызывает проблемы в написании подобного условия?

Comment: @Kromster естественно незнание, может вы подскажите как будет правильно все это написать? и я же написал что, кнопка активно если одно из них заполнено, может быть что 1 незаполнено

Comment: Вы поменяли вопрос. Ок. Теперь `Кнопка активна = поле 1 заполнено ИЛИ поле 2 заполнено;` Так что же у вас вызывает затруднения? Проверка заполнености, оператор ИЛИ, что-то еще?

Comment: @Kromster   if(mail.length >= 1 || phone.length >=1 ) {
            $('#btnCheckPolicy').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnCheckPolicy').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } 
пишу же так не рбаотает

Comment: Посмотрите, `mail.length` и `phone.length` по отдельности дают правильные значения? Каждое из условий `>=1` по отдельности тоже правильно работает? А вместе - нет? Добавьте скобок по смыслу, не повредит `if((mail.length >= 1) || (phone.length >=1))`. А деактивация кнопки сама по себе тоже работает?